# Firebird SQL: Finding bottlenecks / performance analysis

Tags: performance, optimization, firebird, analysis

I am using Firbird 2.5 for some applications. What I miss is a performance analyses tool, e.g. for Visual Studio, which shows what methods / queries have been executed over time.
I am thinking of a tool like Apple's Instruments:

http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/1115/instrumentswindow.jpg

Is there anything like this?
Thanks,
Norbert

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [sinatica](http://www.sinatica.com/), [IB-aid](http://www.ib-aid.com/) or [IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.com)

Comment: Thanks. But I thought more of an source code scanner than a database server tool.